# SQL Server Stuck Processes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am running SQL Server 2012.

I use [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) to see running processes in SQL. I sometimes have to stop stuck queries by doing `KILL Session ID` that works sometimes but lately there have been some queries that are stuck and stopping other queries. When I run the Kill command it says that the command completed but the process is still there.

I cannot seem to get some of these queries to stop.

Is there a better way to force kill processes?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Kill is all you gonna get. Can't you use the information from sp_whoisactive to improve things? Instead of looking for an efficient way to kill processes?

Comment: How do queries get "stuck"? Deadlocked, blocked, or an actual bug in SQL Server that causes the query to never complete?

Comment: Making a habit of regularly killing processes is not a good idea in my humble opinion, I'd recommend finding out what resources the query is waiting on, or what blocking is occurring and try to solve the issue that way. And if you find out that it's some dev running adhoc queries on your production db, then by all means, kill away! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KILL is what you've got. Do keep in mind that some processes (especially those that have been running for a long time) will take time to rollback its transactions as well - it's not necessarily an immediate command.